# @SQLInsert dynamic database schema

Tags: java, hibernate, reflection, orm

I have a need to call a stored procedure on insert of an entity. To do this, I am using `@SQLInsert`, which is working well. The problem I'm facing is that I need to be able to change part of the string during integration tests, as we use a different database schema.

Entity (getters/setters removed for space savings):

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "SNIPPET")
@SQLInsert(sql = "{ call MY_SCHEMA.INSERT_SNIPPET (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?) }", callable = true)
public class Snippet extends BaseDomain {

@Lob
@Column(name = "SNIPPET_TEXT_V2", nullable = false)
private String snippetText;

@Column(name = "ORDER", nullable = false)
private int snippetOrder; //1 based.

@Column(name = "NOTES", nullable = true)
private String snippetNotes;

@Column(name = "STATUS", nullable = false)
@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
private Status status;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "QUERY_ID")
private Query query;

}
```

This is the line I want to be able to change at runtime/test startup:
    `@SQLInsert(sql = "{ call MY_SCHEMA.INSERT_SNIPPET (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?) }", callable = true)`

I need to make `MY_SCHEMA` variable/adjustable at runtime. Is there a way to do this via reflection or other means?

A couple of things to note -

- Setting the default schema on my connection doesn't work. We use
  `USER_SCHEMA` to connect to the DB and keep objects stored in
  `MY_SCHEMA`. Changing the default schema to `MY_SCHEMA` and using `{
  call INSERT_SNIPPET (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?) }` would have adverse effects
  on other parts of our application.
- Versions - oracle 11g, java 8, hibernate 5.2

Comment: I would look to other ways to define custom schema than using this annotation, or to configure env in such way that it can be this same schema. As modifying annotations in runtime for tests does not sound like good idea + it needs to be done before framework will read them as for sure it will save it in some other data structure.

Comment: This annotation is used to override the insert logic, not to define a custom schema. Not using the appropriate mechanism for accomplishing this because of test wiring doesn't seem like a great plan.

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution: using `{h-schema}` 
 that uses the property `spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.default_schema value`.

Example:

```
@SQLInsert(check=ResultCheckStyle.NONE, sql = "insert into {h-schema}tabla (campo1, campo2, campo3, campo4, campo5) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)")
```